# apache-httpclient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4) in android

Tags: android, apache

I am working on mobile application and sending POST requests to HTTP server (PHP) but getting below responce on server side.

> 2016-10-17T12:19:32.227+05:30 [RTR/1] [OUT] dev-chr.cfapps.io -     [17/10/2016:06:49:32.219 +0000] "POST /v1/api_user_login HTTP/1.1" 200 207 92 "-    " "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" 10.10.66.121:36101     x_forwarded_for:"103.9.13.149" x_forwarded_proto:"http"     vcap_request_id:e371662e-e09a-43eb-7ea3-02c5421f7c85 response_time:0.007761781     app_id:c0f2adeb-cf5b-46fa-89c2-8c1ce85d00c4 app_index:0

So is it related to Android 5.0 if yes so I have tried

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Please help me to solve this ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You want a different user-agent string?

Comment: I am working on login web service and it returns the user agent as Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4) so I am unable to get proper response for login.

Comment: So fix you web service so that it gives a proper response regardless of the user-agent string the client sends?